# soft keyboard not appearing

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog, android-softkeyboard

I have a following dialog:

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;

public class IpDiscoveryDialog extends AlertDialog implements View.OnClickListener {

    private View view;
    private Context context;
    private Activity activity;

    private EditText ipEditText;


    protected IpDiscoveryDialog(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.context = context;
    }

    public IpDiscoveryDialog(Context context, Activity activity) {
        this(context);
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public void setContentView(int layoutResID) {
        View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(layoutResID, null);
        this.view = view;
        this.setContentView(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void setContentView(@NonNull View view) {
        super.setContentView(view);
        this.buildView(view);
        this.setCancelable(false);
    }

    private void buildView(View view) {
        view.findViewById(R.id.ipConfirmButton).setOnClickListener(this);
        this.ipEditText = view.findViewById(R.id.ipEditText);
    }
}
```

I open it from a different activity like this:

```
IpDiscoveryDialog ipDiscoveryDialog = new IpDiscoveryDialog(ScanDevicesActivity.this, ScanDevicesActivity.this);
ipDiscoveryDialog.create();
ipDiscoveryDialog.setContentView(R.layout.ip_discovery_dialog);
ipDiscoveryDialog.show();
```

And the layout of the dialog is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/set_ip_address"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/ipEditText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/ip_address"
        android:importantForAutofill="no"
        android:inputType="text" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ipConfirmButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/confirm" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The problem I have is that no matter what I do, I cannot open soft keyboard to edit that `EditText`. I tried open it manually in code, I tried different settings, nothing works.

Code like this does not work:

```
InputMethodManager mImm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);  
mImm.showSoftInput(SearchEdit, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

What else can I try? What is the issue here?

Comment: try to remove `android:inputType` attribute

Comment: It did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this class

```
public class IpDiscoveryDialog extends AlertDialog implements View.OnClickListener {

private View view;
private Context context;
private Activity activity;

private EditText ipEditText;


protected IpDiscoveryDialog(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.context = context;
}

public IpDiscoveryDialog(Context context, Activity activity) {
    this(context);
    this.activity = activity;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setContentView(R.layout.ip_discovery_dialog);
    getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM);
    getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
    buildView();
    this.setCancelable(false);
}

private void buildView() {
    findViewById(R.id.ipConfirmButton).setOnClickListener(this);
    this.ipEditText = findViewById(R.id.ipEditText);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

}
}
```

Comment: Since this is dialog, it will always trigger NullPointerException on findViewById. However getWindow() lines solved my issue, thanks!

Comment: it will not, since he has `this.activity = activity;`

Answer (score 0):

try adding below code in menifext file -

```
 <application
    .....
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true">
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    ipDiscoveryDialog .setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
        @Override
        public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {

            ((InputMethodManager)context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to `post` showSoftInput? I use a utility function for this:

```
public static void showSoftKeyboard(EditText v) {
    Context c = v.getContext();
    InputMethodManager keyboard = (InputMethodManager)
            c.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    v.requestFocus();
    keyboard.showSoftInput(v, 0);
}

public static boolean postShowSoftKeyboard(final EditText v) {
    return v.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            showSoftKeyboard(v);
        }
    });
}
```